# Sign in with different google account Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am new to iOS and Firebase in general and I'm struggling to find out how I can get the app to show the google oAuth modal when I click the signin button. At the moment, it comes up on the first signup instance, but I have to delete the app to get it working again. This can be a bit cumbersome if someone wants to change google accounts.

```
// Google Sign In
@IBAction func gooSignInBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

When I call sign out, it signs out, but the below modal doesn't show up again. It just automatically signs into the last signed in google account.

Does the `try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()` function only sign out the member temporarily?

```
@IBAction func signOut(sender: AnyObject) {
            try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
            FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener({ (auth: FIRAuth, user: FIRUser?) in
                if let user = user {
                    // User is signed in.
                    print(user)
                } else {
                    // No user is signed in.
                    print("user signed out")
                }
            })
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()` for signout

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.